# How to get each Xbits from a int with python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I want to get the each x bits from a int and map these x bits to a list, so after that we have a list with 32/x elements.

For example the number 0xFEBA1234 extracting every 4bits, the result is [15, 14, 11, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4].

generally we can write function like this

```
def get_xbits_list(num, x):
    result = []
    mask = 2**x - 1

    for i in xrange(32/x):
       result.append((num >> (i * x)) & mask)

    result.reverse()
    return result
```

**The Question is:**

Is there any easy way can rewrite this function in one or two line with map or other map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a shorter way (using list comprehension):

```
def get_xbits_list(num, x):
    mask = 2**x - 1
    return [(num >> (i * x)) & mask for i in reversed(xrange(32/x))]
```

If you really want to use `map`:

```
def get_xbits_list(num, x):
    mask = 2**x - 1
    return map(lambda i: (num >> (i * x)) & mask, reversed(xrange(32/x)))
```

Comment: thanks,um is there some function like map, but do not generate list, more like `todo(i) for i in xrange(10)` in function mode such as unknow(todo, xrange(10)).

Comment: @tywtyw2002 I think you're looking for [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=imap#itertools.imap).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def get_xbits_list(num, x):
...     mask = 2**x - 1
...     return list(reversed([(num >> (i * x)) & mask for i in xrange(32//x)]))
>>> get_xbits_list(0xFEBA1234, 4)
[15L, 14L, 11L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L]
```

Note, I changed the `32/x` to `32//x` to explicitly specify floor division because [`32/4` returns a float in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).